# Installing RMagick Gem

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rmagick

I just wanted to `gem install rmagick`

and got this:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:1
```

ImageMagick and libmagickwand-dev is already installed.

Using Ubuntu Linux.

Any help?

Yours, Joern.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use rvm to install ruby (preferred) or use apt-get install ruby ruby-dev

```
aptitude install build-essential imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
gem install rmagick
```

--Edit 1--

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

You will also need ruby-dev (or ruby-full) for successfully compiling the RMagick before gem install.

Comment: What about ruby-dev? installed?

Comment: it was ruby-dev, if you post this separately as an answer I will flag this as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

**sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev**

gem install rmagick

or

in gem file

gem 'rmagick'

then run

bundle install

Comment: This isn't going to help. The OP says those packages are already installed, and is running that command. And anyway, an answer was already accepted **three and a half years ago**.

Comment: for some reason, when I added gem 'rmagick' to my gemfile it removed the error could not load rmagic when I start rails, so for that reason, you got my upvote